# Parallel equivalent to "apply" on 3D array in R

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I have a simple piece of code that iterates over a 3D array.  For each `x`, `y`, a function accepts the stack of `z` values and produces a different stack.  This is accomplished quite simply through:

```
result_data <- apply(data, c(1,2), fun)
```

I'd like to parallelize this using `foreach`.  I've tried many variations of constructs like this:

```
result <- foreach(i= 1:nrow(a), .combine=rbind) %dopar% {
  apply(a[i,,], 1, identity)
}
```

In every iteration, the output array differs from the result of `apply` in some way (values rearranged, dimensions changed, etc.)

Can I reproduce the behavior of the original `apply` call using `foreach`?

Note: I tried `parApply` from the `parallel` package but I would prefer a solution with `foreach`, where I can chunk the data by row instead of considering each `x,y` to be its own unit of work (in which case the parallelization overhead seams to swamp the benefit).

Comment: In my tests, `parApply` returns the same results as `apply`, but both return an array with different dimensions than the input because you specified a MARGIN of `c(1,2)`. Do you want a parallel version of `apply`, or do you want a result with the same dimensions as the input?

Comment: @SteveWeston You're right about `parApply`: it looks like I got confused in my initial testing.  A good solution matching the dimensions of `apply`  would be helpful, as would a solution matching the dimensions of the input.  (I'm aware of `plyr::aaply`, but am not seeing a performance benefit from it.)

Answer (score 2):

The iterators package contains the `iapply` function which can be used for parallel apply operations. It avoids sending the entire array to each of the workers, using less memory.

For example:

```
redim <- function(r) {
  dim(r) <- c(4,2,3)
  r
}

result <- foreach(x=iapply(a, c(1,2)), .combine='c', .final=redim) %dopar% {
  fun(x)
}
```

Note that this uses the `redim` function to convert the result to the correct dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

For example, if you want an equivalent to `apply(a, c(1, 2), identity)`, you can use

```
result <- foreach(i = 1:ncol(a), .final = simplify2array) %dopar% {
  apply(a[, i, ], 1, identity)
}
```